Quick find the unique answer, it may not be unique otherwise!
Replace the question mark with the correct 5-digit number.



                    In order:

                              74905
                              17126
                              83372
                              68503
                                ?
                              79124
                              89076


No knowledge required (googling etc). Just gotta make sense of it somehow.

The answer is

32546!


The rebus indicates

'Puzzling Stack Exchange' - as it is a stack of puzzling pieces with some exchanged

And the numbers

Are the ids of users on the site with names of days of the week!

74905 - @Monday Puzzles
17126 - @Tuesday
83372 - @Wednesday Spam
68503 - @NextThursday
  ?
79124 - @Saturday
89076 - @Sunday udegbu

So

We need the id of a user with 'Friday' in their name - and as the title indicates, as of right now there is only one: @Friday with id number 32546!


Hmm a little bit disappointed with this one.

Well done! That's the correct number. First image shows gjb fgnpxf bs chmmyr cvrprf, frpbaq vzntr fubjf gjb fznyyre fgnpxf rkpunatrq. Guvf rkpunatr bs chmmyr cvrpr fgnpxf jnf vagraqrq gb tvir lbh n uvag gung vg'f fbzrguvat eryngrq gb Chmmyvat Fgnpx Rkpunatr)

@Prim3numbah yep, already realised and edited in, took me a second
